# How do I destroy this UIDatePicker? It won't die

Tags: objective-c

I don't understand! I'm a novice, so this may be my fundamental misunderstanding of Objective-C, life, the universe and/or everything; please be gentle.

1. I set the inputView for a text field to be self.datePicker - a standard UIDatePicker, which has been initialised in viewDidLoad.
2. I add some subviews to the datePicker. Sounds crazy, I know, but bear with me.
3. I now have that field resign first responder, and call self.datePicker = nil. Even more crazy, yes.
4. I tap the textField again, and expect one of two things. Either one, no datePicker. I destroyed it, right? Needs to be re-allocated and initialised. Or two, a fresh datePicker, without the extra subviews. Not sure why I expect this (again, I destroyed it!), but hey, it's possible.
5. What I get is the same picker, complete with the added subviews, plus any date that was previously set in it! What the what?!? says I.

I know you're wondering why I want to do this. Why add views to datePicker at all, and why not just remove them from their superview when needed. But let's assume I have a good reason for doing this, and doing it this way. Can anyone correct my obviously wonky understanding of object behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are two references to the datePicker, but you're only setting one of them to nil.  If I follow you, the two references are self.datePicker and textField.inputView.  But you're only setting the first one to nil.  So the object is "retained" by textField.inputView.

In general, it seems pretty shaky to rely on ARC to destroy objects.  Also, once the datePicker is destroyed, wont' textField.inputView just be nil instead of a new datePicker?

Comment: Yep, that's what I said: the object is retained by the textField's inputView property.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Set textField.inputView = nil. Then tapping on the field gives the keyboard (need to alloc/init the datePicker again). I hadn't thought of inputView as retaining a reference.

Thanks for this. I know it's a weird sounding scenario, but this has helped my understanding of ARC.

Answer (score 1):

No you did not destroyed just just nilled the property on your viewController.
I think you design might be a bit off, but if you created some kind of custom datepicker you should add a reset methods that should return the custom datepicker to base state.

To remove it from the `UITextField` just the the `inputView` properties to a new instance of the datepicker.

Comment: But if I really wanted to remove it entirely, and re alloc/init it, how could I do that? Rather than simply reset it to base state. (tried simply calling alloc/init on it again, to no avail)